# How deserialization process is aware of serialVersionId of the serialized object when serialVersionId is not stored in the serialized object?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

How deserialization process is aware of serialVersionId of the serialized object when serialVersionId is not stored in the serialized object which is required to compare with serial version id of the class it will be converted to, to check if it is compatible?

Comment: Who says the serialized object does not include the `serialVersionId`?

Comment: I think serialization process doesn't store static members of the class

Comment: That's normally the case, but `serialVersionId` is special.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede It isn't special in the sense that the serialized object is magically made to include `serialVersionUID`. It isn't. The mechanism is quite different. That's why `serialVersionIUID` disagreements are detected *before* the object is deserialized.

Comment: @EJP The version is serialized *with* the object, if not as part of its structure, right? It becomes part of the serialized representation of the object.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html) describes the serialized form of a Java object:

```
AC ED: STREAM_MAGIC. Specifies that this is a serialization protocol.
00 05: STREAM_VERSION. The serialization version.
0x73: TC_OBJECT. Specifies that this is a new Object.
0x72: TC_CLASSDESC. Specifies that this is a new class.
00 0A: Length of the class name.
53 65 72 69 61 6c 54 65 73 74: SerialTest, the name of the class.
05 52 81 5A AC 66 02 F6: SerialVersionUID, the serial version identifier of this class.
(fields omitted)
```

Answer (score 1):

**serialVersionUID**  is a `static final long` that is serialized with its class.

If you do not manually provide one for your class, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value.

You can find more details on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a
>   serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects
>   of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
>   the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit
>   serialVersionUID, so they always have the default computed value, but
>   the requirement for matching serialVersionUID values is waived for
>   array classes.

Comment: but, static variables won't get serialized with serialization... ?

Comment: That's right... except for serialVersionUID! It is a "special" variable that is handled differently by the serialization process.

Comment: It isn't 'serialized with its class', because its class isn't serialized.

Answer (score 0):

When the object is serialized, first a descriptor of its *class* is serialized (once only), and that descriptor contains the `serialVersionUID`. It isn't transmitted as part of the object's static state.

See [`newClassDesc` in the Object Serialization Specification, Object Serialization Stream Protocol chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#a10258).